# Testing a connection to S3 from an EC2 Instance using Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm attempting to establish whether an EC2 instance can reach S3. Currently I'm doing this through an upload:

```
try:
    # Create empty ping file
    subprocess.run(['touch', '/tmp/ping'])

    # Run upload commands
    upload_result = subprocess.run(['aws', 's3', 'cp', '/tmp/ping', 's3://mybucket/ping'])
    
    # Check if it succeeded
    upload_result.check_returncode()
except Exception as e:
    print('Could not reach S3')
```

However, I'm wondering if there's a more efficient (non-boto) way of doing this. The EC2 Instance does not have `s3:getObject` permissions, only `s3:putObject` which is intended. But if there's a way to establish it by a simple HTTPS request or something similar, I would love to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things here that are not ideal:

1. shelling out to the awscli (I would use the boto3 SDK instead)
2. invoking a mutating operation (PutObject) simply to test connectivity

You might consider giving this Lambda function read access to a specific sentinel object (e.g. s3://mybucket/headtest) and then invoke [HeadObject](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_object) against it.